# Objective C: Track number of app uses

Tags: objective-c, review

I'm  trying to implement a UIAlertView to ask the user to rate the app, but I only want it to appear after x amount of uses. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could use this open-source library: http://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/ 
(link of github project: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/ )

Even the UIAlertView is provided for you ;)

But to answer your question: you can increase a value in NSUserDefaults each time the user starts the application.

Hope this helps,
Moszi